# n-ary curry in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, coffeescript

I was playing with CoffeeScript when I found myself writing the following lines and then looking at them in awe:

```
compose = (f, g) -> (x) -> f g x
curry = (f) -> (x) -> (y) -> f(x, y)
uncurry = (f) -> (x, y) -> (f x) y
```

How nice, did I think! Now, as an exercise, I thought I would generalize the curry and uncurry functions to n args, to obtain something similar to this:

```
curry2 = (f) -> (x) -> (y) -> f(x, y)
curry3 = (f) -> (x) -> (y) -> (z) -> f(x, y, z)
curry4 = (f) -> (x) -> (y) -> (z) -> (t) -> f(x, y, z, t)
```

And the same thing for uncurry:

```
uncurry2 =  (f) -> (x, y) -> (f x) y
uncurry3 = (f) -> (x, y, z) -> ((f x) y) z
uncurry4 = (f) -> (x, y, z, t) -> (((f x) y) z) t
```

Writing the n-ary uncurry was not very hard:

```
uncurry = (n) -> (f) -> (args...) ->
    if n == 1
        f args[0]
    else
        ((uncurry n - 1) f args.shift()) args...
```

On the other hand, I can't figure out how to get the n-ary curry to work. I thought of implementing first a curry_list function that is the generalization of this suite:

```
curry_list2 = (f) -> (x) -> [x, y]
curry_list3 = (f) -> (x) -> (z) -> [x, y, z]
curry_list4 = (f) -> (x) -> (z) -> (t) -> [x, y, z, t]
```

Here's the implementation:

```
curry_list = (n) ->
    curry_list_accum = (n, accum) ->
        if n
            (x) ->
                accum.push x
                curry_list_accum n - 1, accum
        else
            accum
    curry_list_accum n, []
```

And then I would just compose curry_list with function application to obtain currying. That's what I tried to do:

```
curry = (n) ->
    apply_helper = (f) -> (args) -> f args...
    (f) -> compose (apply_helper f), (curry_list n)
```

But for some reason, it does not work. For exemple, trying to evaluate

```
curry(3)((a,b,c) -> a + b + c)(1)(2)(3)
```

yields the following error:

> Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type

Now after jotting some more notes I understand that trying to compose f with curry_list is incorrect. I do have the intuition that what I'm looking for is something that looks like this composition, but is not exactly that. Am I correct in thinking that?

Finally, what would be a correct implementation?

Comment: I'm in awe reading your question.  +1, good sir.

Comment: This JS implementation I wrote a while back might point you in the right direction: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=138769

Comment: +1 for seriously confusing me. For a moment I thought I was looking at haskell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning the composed function after `curry(3)((a,b,c) -> a + b + c)`, not the accumulator.

That means `((args) -> f args...)` is receiving a function as argument, your code doesn't wait until the argument list is complete to call `f`.

Maybe implement this without composition?

```
accumulator = (n, accum, f) ->
    return f accum... if n is 0
    (x) ->
        accum.push x
        accumulator n - 1, accum, f

curry = (n) ->
    (f) -> accumulator n, [], f

curry(3)((a,b,c) -> a + b + c)(1)(2)(3) # 6
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it gets any simpler than this:

```
Function::curry = (n) ->
  if n is 1 then @ else (x) => (=> @ x, arguments...).curry(n-1)
```

Basically if the arity requested is greater than 1 then it consumes an argument and returns another function and constructs a ladder of functions along the way. It does so until the arity is 1, in which case it climbs up the ladder of functions it created. The ladder adds the consumed arguments into a list until the function at the top of the ladder, which is the user provided one, gets called.

Here's some tests I wrote in case you're interested:

```
add3 = ((a,b,c) -> a+b+c).curry 3
add3_1 = add3 1
add3_1_2 = add3_1 2

console.log add3_1(4)(5) is 10
console.log add3_1(4)(6) is 11
console.log add3_1_2(4) is 7
console.log add3_1(5)(5) is 11
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look to me like composition. The last `curry` implementation you have seems to make no distinction between the function to be curried and the arguments to that function, whereas it would seem that such a distinction is rather important. How about something like this?

```
curry = (n, f) ->
    acc = []
    helper = (x) ->
        acc.push x
        if acc.length is n then f acc... else helper
```

Comment: Elegant answer! In the question, I wrote the function in curried style, so that would be `curry = (n) -> (f) ->` to do exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

A related generalization is presented in [Partial with Free Variables](http://autotelicum.github.com/Smooth-CoffeeScript/literate/partial.html).

Comment: By the way, in the partialFree implementation, why is b reversed? Wouldn't `func (for arg in a then arg ?= b.shift())...` do?

Answer (score 0):

I got really interested in solving this, so I wrote this up. It probably needs a few tweaks, but it works awesomely as far as I have tested. Basically just call f.curry() which returns partially applied functions in succession.. until you call it with the last argument that it takes, which is when that partial calls the one before it and so on, all the way back down the the original f.

```
partial = (f, args1...) -> (args2...) ->
  f.apply @, args1.concat args2
partial$ = (f, args) ->
  partial.apply @, [f].concat args

Function::curry = (args...) ->
  curry$ = (n, f, args...) ->
    curry$$ = (n, f, args...) ->
      if n > args.length
        partial curry$$, (n - args.length), (partial$ f, args)
      else f args
    curry$$ (n - args.length), (partial$ f, args)
  curry$.apply @, [@length, @].concat args
```

Now we can do things like this:

```
twoToThe = Math.pow.curry 2

32 == twoToThe 5
32 == Math.pow.curry()(2)(5)
32 == Math.pow.curry()(2, 5)
32 == Math.pow.curry(2, 5)
32 == Math.pow.curry(2)(5)

# And just for laughs:
32 == Math.pow.curry()()()(2)()()()(5)
```